# Is academician synonymous to academic?

Tags: synonyms

In several recent calls for papers for conferences in my area of science I have started noticing people apparently using the term 'academician' synonymously to 'academic'. An example:

> The symposium will provide an excellent platform for knowledge exchange between researchers, scientists, **academicians** and engineers working in the areas listed here:

Looking up the term in [Merrian-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/academician), this does not seem to correspond quite to what I usually think of as an academic, i.e. someone who works in research and/or teaching at an academic institution - typically a university:

> a : a member of an academy for promoting science, art, or literature

It does also list 'academic' as a meaning of the word, so I guess it might be OK. Is it just me that has the impression that the 'academician' term has started popping up a lot recently?

Comment: They're normally just called *academics*.

Comment: I think that *as nouns* they're synonymous in most cases (OED says the longer form is *now chiefly US*). But checking [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=academicians%2Cacademics&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cacademicians%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cacademics%3B%2Cc0) for the ***plural*** versions (to screen out adjectival usages of the shorter form), it's pretty obvious the longer form is on the way out.

Answer (score 2):

*Academician* is used to mean a member of a specific academy, in a sense almost akin to *fellow*. *Which* academy may be implied by the context rather than stated (unlike *fellow*). It seems particularly common in the former Soviet Union.

You may be seeing a mistranslation, or a misplaced attempt at an honorific, similar to "Dear Professor or Learned Scholar" (which almost always indicates a spam or fake conference, but just occasionally doesn't). Either way I doubt it's from a native speaker.

Comment: I do not mean to apply too much prejudice here, although I probably am, but I seem to have noticed this in conference invitations from China / South East Asia.